# Django Rest Framework: Issue using OrderingFilter and django-filter simultaneously

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a viewset which needs to have both flexible ordering by parameter and filtering by parameter for a custom `list()` over-ride. I am able to get ordering to work as well as filtering on various parameters via `django-filter`, but I cannot get them both to function simultaneously.

Here is my simplified `views.py` code that works for ordering the results:

```
class AssetViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, AssetPaginationMixin,):

    queryset = Asset.objects.all()
    pagination_class = AssetPagination
    serializer_class = serializers.AssetSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, )
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'session_id')
    filter_class = AssetFilterSet

    def list(self, request):
        assets = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(assets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And here is the code that works for filtering:

```
class AssetViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, AssetPaginationMixin,):

    queryset = Asset.objects.all()
    pagination_class = AssetPagination
    serializer_class = serializers.AssetSerializer
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, )
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'session_id')
    filter_class = AssetFilterSet

    def list(self, request):
        assets = AssetFilterSet(request.query_params)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(assets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And finally, my `filters.py` code:

```
class AssetFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    project_id = django_filters.NumberFilter()
    submitted = django_filters.TypedChoiceFilter(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES, coerce=strtobool) 
    class Meta:
        model = Asset
        fields = ['project',
                  'submitted']
```

The only difference is the first line in `list()`. For some reason, it seems like the `AssetFilterSet` needs to be applied directly within `list()` in order to take effect and is otherwise bypassed if I use `self.filter_queryset` in `list()` despite being specified by `filter_class = AssetFilterSet`.

Comment: Why not subclass `viewset.ListViewSet` or `viewset.ModelViewSet` since you are using a model, then you don't need to provide `list` since it will be inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Turns out it is a very simple fix; you must include BOTH `DjangoFilterBackend` and `OrderingFilter` as `filter_backends` explicitly despite `DjangoFilterBackend` being specified globally in SETTINGS.

Here's the working code:

```
class AssetViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet, AssetPaginationMixin,):

    queryset = Asset.objects.all()
    pagination_class = AssetPagination
    serializer_class = serializers.AssetSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'session_id')
    filter_class = AssetFilterSet

    def list(self, request):
        assets = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(assets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I was under the impression that specifying `DjangoFilterBackend` in SETTINGS meant that it would be included by default and adding a `filter_backends` filter would add to it, not replace it. Live and learn!